# replace NA of numeric columns with both numeric and character values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, na, missing-data

I have a dataframe df with multiple columns.
two of them ( columns AGE and SALARY ), are of type double.
I want to replace the missing value of column AGE with 0 and 
missing value of column SALARY with "not found". 

what is the most efficient way to do so?

```
replace_na(df, list(AGE=0, SALARY="not found"))
```

I get error :

```
Error in `stop_vctrs()`:
! Can't convert `replace$SALARY` <character> to match type of `data$SALARY` <double>.
Backtrace:
 1. tidyr::replace_na(df, list(AGE= 0, SALARY= "not found"))
 2. tidyr:::replace_na.data.frame(df, list(AGE= 0, SALARY= "not found"))
 3. vctrs::vec_assign(...)
 4. vctrs `<fn>`()
 5. vctrs::vec_default_cast(...)
 6. vctrs::stop_incompatible_cast(...)
 7. vctrs::stop_incompatible_type(...)
 8. vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
 9. vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)
```

edit : this is the source of my dataset : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cKxzNrnIMq4RxdMcBz3nlr7YtYaPhn5_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you please show the `dput` of your example.  The code is working for this example i..e `df <- data.frame(AGE = c(NA, 2, 3, 5, 7), SALARY = c(4, 3, NA, 7, 5));
replace_na(df, list(AGE=0, SALARY="not found"))`

Comment: thank you @akrun, I get another type of error with your df. however I added my df link in  the post. I  m not sure how to share a csv file on stackoverflow. sorry.

Comment: It could be an issue with the `packageVersion('tidyr')`.  I used `1.1.3`

Comment: The column names are not upper case in your data linked  `replace_na(df, list(Age=0, Salary="not found")) %>% nrow#
[1] 10` i.e. there is no column named 'AGE' or 'SALARY' .  The names are `Age` and `Salary` (`R` is case-sensitive)

Comment: Right. in my actual code its fixed. I updated the tidyr package . now I get the error 
Error in `check_replacement()`:
! Replacement for `data` is length 2, not length 1.
Backtrace:
 1. tidyr::replace_na(df, list(AGE = 0, SALARY = "not found"))
 2. tidyr:::replace_na.default(df, list(AGE = 0, SALARY= "$$$"))
 3. tidyr:::check_replacement(replace, "data")

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't reproduce your issues with the data you linked

Comment: @Akrun, you ve always been helpful :) .

Answer (score 12):

I ran into the same problem after updating tidyr to version 1.2.0

From the changelog for tidyr:

> replace_na() no longer allows the type of data to change when the replacement is applied. replace will now always be cast to the type of data before the replacement is made. For example, this means that using a replacement value of 1.5 on an integer column is no longer allowed. Similarly, replacing missing values in a list-column must now be done with list("foo") rather than just "foo".

You are trying to convert two columns, 'Age' and 'Salary'.

Converting 'Age' by itself should work because it is probably type double, and you are converting the NAs to 0, also type double.

`mutate(Age = replace_na(Age, 0) #This should work`

But when you try to `replace_na` in 'Salary' with a string "not found", you have to convert the column to **character**. `replace_na` used to do this automatically, but it no longer does. You can fix this by adding a call to **as.character**

`mutate(Salary = replace_na(Salary, "not found") #used to work`

New method:

`mutate(Salary = replace_na(as.character(Salary), "not found") #New method`

Answer (score 0):

To judge by the linked data, you seem to have **blank** data cells rather than `NA`. If that's correct then this should work:

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    AGE = ifelse(AGE == "", 0, AGE),
    SALARY = ifelse(SALARY == "", "not found", SALARY)
  )
  AGE    SALARY
1   0         4
2   2         3
3   3 not found
4   5         7
5   7         5
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(AGE = c("", 2, 3, 5, 7), 
                 SALARY = c(4, 3, "", 7, 5))
```

Comment: This is what I had tried first. however I got : Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "NULL"

Comment: Please post a snippet of your data, e.g., by using `dput(yourdata)`. With your real data or just a small snippet of it, we can surely help you.